# C# WPF uEye Camera capture video

Tags: c#, wpf, camera

I have program to capture video from camera. Application is in windows form and I want use this code to WPF application but it is not working.
I use handle to capture image from uEye camera. In windows form is it

```
displayHandle = PictureBox.Handle
```

But when I use handle in WPF then I not received video from camera.
In WPF i use this handle

```
HwndSource hwndSource = HwndSource.FromVisual(pbMainImage) as HwndSource;
displayHandle = hwndSource.Handle;
```

But still not working it

Both handle I used after

```
InitializeComponent();
```

---

```
private void onFrameEvent(object sender, EventArgs e){
  uEye.Camera Camera = sender as uEye.Camera;

  Int32 s32MemID;
  Camera.Memory.GetActive(out s32MemID);
  Camera.Display.Render(s32MemID, displayHandle, uEye.Defines.DisplayRenderMode.FitToWindow);
}
```

displayHandle si handle from component pictureImage.

Thanks for help.

Comment: 'it is not working' isn't a very useful way to describe your issue. Can you define exactly *how* it's not working? Exceptions? Things not recognised? Does it run and then fail? Does it not run at all?

Comment: image component doesn't show video from camera. But I got idea. how to fix it. If it will be working I write solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 HwndSource hwndSource = HwndSource.FromVisual(pbMainImage) as HwndSource;
displayHandle = hwndSource.Handle;
```

Do not use after

```
InitializeComponent();
```

because hwndSource is null then Camera not recognize handle. You can create handle before use handle not after initialize component.

Comment: Hi, I am running into the same issue. Did you managed to bind the camera view to a Wpf image?

Answer (score 0):

Straming IDS camera to WPF component.

```
private void onFrameEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      uEye.Camera Camera = sender as uEye.Camera;

      Int32 s32MemID;
      Camera.Memory.GetActive(out s32MemID);
      if (frameCamera != null)
            frameCamera.Dispose();
      frameCamera = null;
      Camera.Memory.ToBitmap(s32MemID, out frameCamera);

      Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
      {
            pbMainImage.Source = loadBitmap(frameCamera);
      }));
}
```

> loadBitmap(frameCamera) - Convert Bitmap to BitmapSource

Comment: Hi, and how do you handle memory usage? In my app grows memory usage up to several GB before it will be collected. Manually calling GC.Collect after each Frame causes lower latency of other threads.